# typescript: Import only type from json file

Tags: json, typescript, webpack

Is there any way to import just `JSON` file `type`? I have a complex `JSON` file and I need it's definition to be used in whole application, but when I do  `import * as data from 'data.json'`, whole file is imported, which causes its presence in build (using webpack). As far as I know, there is no way to exclude it in `webpack config`.

EDIT:
My question might be a little bit unclear, so here is my example:

```
import * as data from 'data.json'
// data looks like this:
// { 
//   a: {
//    b: 'something1'
//   },
//   c: {
//    d: 'something2'
//   }
// } 

export type typedJson = typeof data;
// which should show on hover/autocomplete: { "a": { "b": "string" }, "c": { "d": "string" } }
```

But when I do that, whole `data.json` file is imported and it's present in webpack bundle. Is there any way to have those typings and exclude it from bundle?

Comment: Hi, @ichi just saw this question of yours but please can you tell me what is meant by "**_just JSON file type_**". What is file type ? NOTE: I've little experience with JSON.

Comment: So basically what you want is having only the keys instead of the whole file including contents?

Comment: I've updated question, I hope now it's clear. @sandrooco yes, this is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an import type to get just the type of the json file:

```
type JsonDataType = typeof import('./data.json')
```

Comment: It seems, that my problem where somewhere else. So my example, which I thought was wrong, works fine too:
`import * as data from 'data.json'; export type typedJson = typeof data;`